# How to plot a power curve by following code?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, python-3.6

In the code, I tried to plot a graph Power(p) vs voltage (Vpv) but my code is not giving the result.

```
import numpy as np
import math
from numpy import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('ggplot')

r = 50
Vpv = np.linspace(0,0.6,r) # Vpv = panel voltage

Rs = 0  # series resistance
Rsh = math.inf  # parallel resistance
n = 2       # ideality constant depends on semiconductor material
m = 1.5     # another constant depends on dopping
T = 298    # temperature in kelvin
Eg = 1.14   # band gap energy in ev
K = 0.13      # constant
Vt = T/11600  #thermal voltage
Io = K*(T**m)*exp(-Eg/(n*Vt))   # Io = diode current
print(Io)
Isc = Io*(10**9)

def current():
    current = []  #initializing current array as null
    for t in Vpv:
        Ipv = np.zeros(r)  #initializing panel current(Ipv) as zero  

        Ipv = Isc - Io *(exp((t + Rs*Ipv)/(n*Vt)) - 1) - (t + Rs*Ipv)/Rsh
        current.append(Ipv)
    return np.array(current)

Icurrent = current()
#power = Vpv * Icurrent
power = np.multiply(Vpv, Icurrent)
plt.plot(Vpv,power,'b')
#plt.plot(Vpv,Icurrent,'r')
plt.xlabel('Panel VOltage(V)')
plt.ylabel('Panel Current(A) and Power(W)')
plt.show()
```

Is also tried to use array multiplication like `no.multiply(arr1,arr2)` but this is also not working.

I am getting the following graph using array multiplication - 
[image: Output of the above code]

but it should come in the following shape - 
[image: Expected shape of output]

Any suggestion Welcome.

Comment: please define "not working".

Comment: Is your current() function correct?  The Icurrent array is filled with nearly constant values (154.5xxx).

Comment: Yeah, but I don't what should be changed in current() function to get a single array. I used for loop to vary Vpv and get corresponding values for Ipv. Then I want to make an array of those Ipv values. To do this I wrote this current function. Can anyone suggest a different way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem. I got correct graphs.

```
import numpy as np
import math
from numpy import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('ggplot')

r = 50
Vpv = np.linspace(0,1.1,r) # Vpv = panel voltage

Rs = 0  # series resistance
Rsh = math.inf  # parallel resistance
n = 2       # ideality constant depends on semiconductor material
m = 1.5     # another constant depends on dopping
T = 298    # temperature in kelvin
Eg = 1.14   # band gap energy in ev
K = 0.13      # constant
Vt = T/11600  #thermal voltage
Io = K*(T**m)*exp(-Eg/(n*Vt))   # Io = diode current
print(Io)
Isc = Io*(10**9)

def current():
    current = []  #initializing current array as null
    for t in Vpv:
        Ipv = 0  #initializing panel current(Ipv) as zero  

        Ipv = Isc - Io *(exp((t + Rs*Ipv)/(n*Vt)) - 1) - (t + Rs*Ipv)/Rsh
        current.append(Ipv)
    return np.array(current)

Icurrent = current()
p = Vpv * Icurrent
plt.plot(Vpv,p,'b')
plt.plot(Vpv,Icurrent,'r')
plt.xlabel('Panel VOltage(V)')
plt.ylabel('Panel Current(A)')
plt.ylim(0,max(Icurrent)+ 10)
plt.plot((-0.1, max(Vpv)), (0,0), 'k')
plt.plot((0,0),(-3,8), 'k')
plt.show()
```